# How to make a USB flash memory act like a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, usb, mouse

As you know, Windows 7 and Windows 8 are autorun-protected.

I need to write a script for my USB flash memory in order to make my computer think that it's a keyboard or mouse, so I can use the autorun feature for executing my programs.

Any ideas to do so?

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: superuser.com looks forward to this question ;)

Comment: @duDE +1 ! I'll keep a lookout for it.

Comment: Do you mean making a flash memory bootable with UFDUtility?! I think it doesn't work anymore :-s